# Unmet Dependencies with kdelibs5-data

Tags: kde, dependencies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I resolve unmet dependencies?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)

I was trying to install Amarok 1.4 on Ubuntu 12.04 (Gnome-classic), by following [this](http://skerit.com/en/computer/amarok-1-4-installeren-op-ubuntu-12-04-64bit-precise-pangolin/) instructions. Problem started after giving these two commands

```
dpkg -i kdelibs5-data_4.6.2-0ubuntu4_all.deb

dpkg -i kdelibs-data_3.5.10.dfsg.1-5ubuntu2_all.deb
```

Now, immediately after these commands, Ubuntu Updater popped up and gave me an error that the package catalog is broken and needs to be repaired. Nothing can be installed or removed till then. It also offered a suggestion to run apt-get install -f.

I tried that, but again got the same error.Also tried apt-get clean followed by apt-get

```
install -f.
Again got the following output:

jitesh@jitesh-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get clean
jitesh@jitesh-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  kdelibs5-data
The following packages will be upgraded:
  kdelibs5-data
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 18 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 2,832 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,998 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Get:1 http: //in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/precise-updates/main kdelibs5-data all 4:4.8.4a-0ubuntu0.2 [2,832 kB]
Fetched 2,832 kB in 32s (86.6 kB/s)                                            
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of kdelibs5-data:
 libplasma3 (4:4.8.4a-0ubuntu0.2) breaks kdelibs5-data (<< 4:4.6.80~) and is installed.
  Version of kdelibs5-data to be configured is 4:4.6.2-0ubuntu4.
 kate-data (4:4.8.4-0ubuntu0.1) breaks kdelibs5-data (<< 4:4.6.90) and is installed.
  Version of kdelibs5-data to be configured is 4:4.6.2-0ubuntu4.
 katepart (4:4.8.4-0ubuntu0.1) breaks kdelibs5-data (<< 4:4.6.90) and is installed.
  Version of kdelibs5-data to be configured is 4:4.6.2-0ubuntu4.
dpkg: error processing kdelibs5-data (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of kdelibs-data:
 kdelibs-data depends on kdelibs5-data; however:
  Package kdelibs5-data is not configured yet.
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: error processing kdelibs-data (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 kdelibs5-data
 kdelibs-data
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ precise/partner i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_partner_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

As I thought the error was related to configuring kdelibs, I tried to configure using dpkg. But got the following errors:

```
jitesh@jitesh-desktop:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of kdelibs5-data:
 libplasma3 (4:4.8.4a-0ubuntu0.2) breaks kdelibs5-data (<< 4:4.6.80~) and is installed.
  Version of kdelibs5-data to be configured is 4:4.6.2-0ubuntu4.
 kate-data (4:4.8.4-0ubuntu0.1) breaks kdelibs5-data (<< 4:4.6.90) and is installed.
  Version of kdelibs5-data to be configured is 4:4.6.2-0ubuntu4.
 katepart (4:4.8.4-0ubuntu0.1) breaks kdelibs5-data (<< 4:4.6.90) and is installed.
  Version of kdelibs5-data to be configured is 4:4.6.2-0ubuntu4.
dpkg: error processing kdelibs5-data (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of kdelibs-data:
 kdelibs-data depends on kdelibs5-data; however:
  Package kdelibs5-data is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing kdelibs-data (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 kdelibs5-data
 kdelibs-data
jitesh@jitesh-desktop:~$
```

Now I dont have any idea how to proceed. I am unable to install anything from  Software Centre or using Terminal now.

Some basic info:
Core2Duo, dual booting Ubuntu 12.04 with Win7. Fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04 (not upgrade). Incidentally, I had first upgraded from 10.04 and had succesfully installed Amarok 1.4 following this same method. But due to other issues, i had to format and do a clean install of 12.04. Now when I tried to install Amarok 1.4, I'm getting these errors. I also have digiKam and k3b installed, if that can be of any help. I use digiKam a lot, so removing KDE is not feasible for me.

Any help on this issue will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem just now.

Go to **Synaptic**, select the *broken packages* and mark them to "remove completely". This will remove some other `kde-packages` as well, but just *note* which ones and then reinstall them after. Check for updates afterwards and then everything should be back to how it was before (maybe you lost some configuration data of the KDE programs).

Hope I could help.